# how to access parent module data in child file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

my file are like avilabele this sturucture.

[image]

**sample.js** is root file and **test.js** is avilable in **xx** folder.

***sample.js***

```
    var name={
   h:14
}
module.exports=name;
```

***test.js***

```
var name=require('./sample.js')
console.log(name.h);
```

when a run test.js code using command prompt :

> node test.js

it gives error like :

> Cannot find module './sample.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a file with a relative path, it is relative to the file doing the `require` (see [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)). In `test.js`, `require('./sample.js')` will look for `/path/to/xx/sample.js`. Use `require('../sample.js')` since it is in the parent folder of `test.js`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var name=require('../sample.js')
console.log(name.h);
```

You are requiring module from the parent directory with ".."